# Iterate Map in Apex using Single Iterator?

Tags: apex

In Java we can iterate over Map easily and we can see what values are present for each key.

```
Map<String, String> map = ...
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

How can I do the same in `Apex`?

Sample code:

```
Map<String, String> cityCountryMap = new Map<String, String>();
cityCountryMap.put('India','Delhi');
cityCountryMap.put('Sri Lanka','Colombo');
cityCountryMap.put('Nepal','Bhutan');
cityCountryMap.put('Pakistan','Islamabad');

for(String country : cityCountryMap.keySet()){
    System.debug('Country : '+ country);
}

for(String city : cityCountryMap.values()){
    System.debug('City : '+city);
}
```

Comment: I'd argue that Apex is quite mature, just...quirky.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply

```
   for(String country : cityCountryMap.keySet()){
    System.debug('Country : '+ country);
    System.debug(cityCountryMap.get(country);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use Map.get() to retrieve the value of the key.

```
for(String country : cityCountryMap.keySet()){
    System.debug('Country : '+ country);
    System.debug('City : '+cityCountryMap.get(country));
}
```

Comment: There is an echo on SFSE lately lol. That's a good sign

Comment: The timestamps for both of these answers are 18:13:17... impressive!

Comment: @RobertWatson - How do you see the exact timestamps? I knew we were within seconds of each other. if Santanu had not been so verbose he would have beat me lol

Comment: @Eric if you hover over the "answered X hours ago", a tooltip will appear with the exact time.